# how to refresh data in table view cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have table view cell, that take information about user from server. When I run it, all fields are empty, they show information after I scroll away from screen. But how to refresh it when view did load?

Comment: after getting user info from server, call `[tableView reloadData]`

Comment: in (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method?

Comment: Nope..You need to call reload data from the method where you are parsing user information and update it to ur datasource. After updating datasource call reloadData.

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

This will refresh all your cells so call it when you have the proper information and your cells will be updated with the right information

Comment: when I have to use it?

Comment: after your information is available. Have a look at my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Just call it once you have all the information downloaded that will be used in the (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method. So right after your download from the server is complete call that code

Answer (score 0):

After your information is downloaded and saved (in other words available), follow the following setup.

1. Setup your data source.
2. Provide data like height, number of rows, sections etc. through the data source delegate protocol.
3. Set up delegate methods as required.
4. Finally, after only following the above steps, use this code `[tableView reloadData]`

Let me know if this helps you (or you need any more clarification :P).

Comment: so, I have (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath, where I download data and return cell, so where I must call  [tableView reloadData] ?

Comment: So you download data for each cell individually ??

Comment: I mean, I download it in (void)viewDidLoad, but here there no tableView?

Comment: I'm assuming that your class is tableview delegate. Hence tableview is actually just available as tableView. Start typing in the Xcode it will show you. If still not available can you drag and drop an IBOutlet connection in your class. That way your tableview is available.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //...
    [self dataFromServer];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

it doesn`t work yet

Answer (score 0):

You should also probably check out frameworks such as Sensible TableView. The framework will automatically fetch the data from your server and display it inside the cells, and will make sure they stay up to date. Saved me tons of development time.